# Trouble understanding the "checking-winner" algorithm behind tic-toe game in android java by Rob Perceival

Tags: java, android, arrays, algorithm, tic-tac-toe

Here is the code for tic-tac toe game in Android Java I am learning for Udemy. I am able to undertand how to get the position of the tap by using setting an android:tag value to every image value. It is stored in tappedCounter. I am not able to decipher why gamestate is taken as 2,2,2,2,2,... and the algorithm behind winning the game.

```
int activePlayer = 0;

boolean gameIsActive = true;

// 2 means unplayed

int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

int[][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

public void dropIn(View view) {

    ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

    if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {

        gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

        if (activePlayer == 0) {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

            activePlayer = 1;

        } else {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

            activePlayer = 0;

        }

        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360).setDuration(300);

        for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {

            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

                // Someone has won!

                gameIsActive = false;

                String winner = "Red";

                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0) {

                    winner = "Yellow";

                }

                TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);

                winnerMessage.setText(winner + " has won!");

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                boolean gameIsOver = true;

                for (int counterState : gameState) {

                    if (counterState == 2) gameIsOver = false;

                }

                if (gameIsOver) {

                    TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);

                    winnerMessage.setText("It's a draw");

                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
```

I am unable to understand this part specially. How is the checking and the array working?

```
for (int[] winningPosition : winningPositions) {

            if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2) {

                // Someone has won!
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not aware of the Udemy course from where you are learning this, but from the given code I can understand the following things.

1. You can assume every cell as positions in a 3x3 board. So the board would appear like this:

   0 1 2

   3 4 5

   6 7 8

Now if are aware of the tic tac toe winning rules, then it should be pretty simple to understand the winningPositions array. It contains all the horizontal, vertical and diagonal paths which would result in a victory.

2. Now to answer your second question, the gamestate is set to 2 initially to indicate that currently all of the cells are unmarked i.e. none of the 2 players have made a move in any of the cells (assigned as 2). So whenever any player would make a move on a cell, it will be marked by the player id (either as 0 or 1).
3. The winning logic then is pretty straightforward. You are simply iterating over all of the path that are possible for any winner and then you are checking if in any of the paths all of the 3 cells are occupied by any one of the players.

   So there are basically 2 things that need to be checked:

   1. All of the 3 cells are equal i.e. occupied by the same player id.

      gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
      gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]]
   2. If the cells are equal then they should be occupied by a player so the value should
      not be equal to 2.

      gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2 indicates that the cells are not unoccupied

For example if player 1 wins by occupying all the top horizontal cells together then the winning position {0 1 2} would all be having the same id as player 1's id.

Hope that is clear!

Comment: What if I miss this line? gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2 . Since gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] is already used in the beginning, is it necessary?

Comment: @OhmBrock yeah it is necessary. As you can see in the point 3.2 above, you are initializing your 3x3 matrix with the value 2. And value 2 means that no one has made any move in that particular cell. So if you don't put this check then after the very first move you will end up declaring the winner since many winning positions will satisfy the remaining condition. Let me know if that is clear enough.

Comment: gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2 here you are basically checking that if in any of the winning paths all of the values are equal then the values should not be equal to 2 since value 2 does not belongs to any player. And you want the cells to have same values but the values should be equal to either of 2 player ids.

Comment: "you don't put this check then after the very first move you will end up declaring the winner ..." Can you elaborate it further?  I have realized that it is important. Thanks, so much. Suppose player A with id=1 starts at postion 0, gamestate will become [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2] . Then how can it satisfy the condition of 0,1,2 after the VERY FIRST MOVE?

Comment: yes you are right. It will not satisfy {0,1,2} after the first move that you mentioned. But it will satisfy other winning conditions, for eg {3,4,5} or {6,7,8} since these positions still have value = 2. That's why you need to check that if all the positions of a winning path are equal then the value at those positions should not be 2 i.e. all the cells that are equal must contain either of the 2 player ids which could be 0 or 1.